# ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 24>" does not exist CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function update_notifications_amount() line 44 at FETCH

Tags: postgresql

Estoy ejecutando un procedimiento almacenado el cual tiene varios ref cursors anidados, y me está dando ese error que no tengo idea qué significa. Ayuda por favor. Estoy usando postgresql

```
create or replace procedure update_notifications_amount()
language plpgsql as $$
declare
  months_range integer;
  days_range integer;
  apply_before_time_range boolean;
  rule_percentage double precision;
  extra_service_id integer;
  is_discount boolean;
  rule_amount double precision;
  payment_id integer;
  notification_created_date timestamp;
  concept_extra_service_id integer;
  payment_cursor refcursor;
  payment_registry eddu_payments%rowtype;
  payment_concept_extra_service_cursor refcursor;
  payment_concept_extra_service_registry eddu_payments_concepts_extra_service%rowtype;
  notifications_cursor refcursor;
  notification_registry eddu_notifications%rowtype;
  difference_month integer;
  difference_day integer;
begin

  open payment_cursor for select * from  eddu_payments where pay_status = 'OPEN';
  loop
    fetch payment_cursor into payment_registry;
    exit when not found;
    payment_id := payment_registry.pay_id;
    open payment_concept_extra_service_cursor for select * from eddu_payments_concepts_extra_service where pay_id = payment_id;
    loop
      fetch from payment_concept_extra_service_cursor into payment_concept_extra_service_registry;
      exit when not found;

      concept_extra_service_id := payment_concept_extra_service_registry.con_ext_ser_id;

      select con_ext_ser_months_range, con_ext_ser_days_range, con_ext_ser_apply_before_time_range, con_ext_ser_percentage, ext_ser_id
      into months_range, days_range, apply_before_time_range, rule_percentage, extra_service_id
      from eddu_concept_extra_services where con_ext_ser_id = concept_extra_service_id;

      select ext_ser_is_discount into is_discount from eddu_extra_services
      where ext_ser_id = extra_service_id;

      open notifications_cursor for select * from eddu_notifications where pay_id = payment_id and not_status = 'OPEN';
      loop
        fetch from notifications_cursor into notification_registry;
        exit when not found;

        raise notice ' notification registry %', notification_registry.not_id;

        notification_created_date := make_date(notification_registry.not_created_year, notification_registry.not_created_month, notification_registry.not_created_day);

        select date_part('year', age(current_date, notification_created_date)) * 12 + date_part('month', age(current_date, notification_created_date)), date_part('day', age(current_date, notification_created_date)) into difference_month, difference_day;

        rule_amount := payment_registry.pay_amount * (rule_percentage / 100);

        if ((months_range is not null and days_range is not null) and (months_range = difference_month and difference_day = (days_range + 1))) or
           ((months_range is null and days_range is not null) and (difference_day = (days_range + 1))) or
           ((months_range is not null and days_range is null) and (months_range = difference_month and difference_day = 1)) then
              if apply_before_time_range is true and is_discount is true then
                update eddu_notifications
                set not_debt_amount = notification_registry.not_debt_amount + rule_amount
                where not_id = notification_registry.not_id;
                commit;
              end if;
              if apply_before_time_range is true and is_discount is false then
                update eddu_notifications
                set not_debt_amount = notification_registry.not_debt_amount - rule_amount
                where not_id = notification_registry.not_id;
                commit;
              end if;
              if apply_before_time_range is false and is_discount is true then
                update eddu_notifications
                set not_debt_amount = notification_registry.not_debt_amount - rule_amount
                where not_id = notification_registry.not_id;
                commit;
              end if;
              if apply_before_time_range is false and is_discount is false then
                update eddu_notifications
                set not_debt_amount = notification_registry.not_debt_amount + rule_amount
                where not_id = notification_registry.not_id;
                commit;
              end if;
        end if;

      end loop;
      close notifications_cursor;
    end loop;
    close payment_concept_extra_service_cursor;
  end loop;
  close payment_cursor;

end;
$$;
```

Comment: ¿Como lo estas llamando? ese error es comunmente cuando estas tratando de acceder a un cursor fuera de una transaccion

Comment: call update_notifications_amount();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo creo que estas teniendo el problema del cierre de las transacciones al usar los  `commit`  dentro del procedure, como el cursor tiene vida dentro de una transaccion cada vez que entra al los `commit`, la cierra, y ese cursor ya no es accesible, tu problema esa algo similar a [este enlace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249446/unable-to-create-commit-inside-postgresql-11-5-procedure), y puede solucionarlo usando SQL dinamico para declarar el cursor con la opción `WITH HOLD` , como comentan en [este enlace](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/with-hold-cursors-and-transactions-in-postgresql/#:%7E:text=WITH%20HOLD%20cursors%20in%20PL/pgSQL%20procedures)

por ejemplo, el siguiente codigo retorna el mismo error tuyo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers2 (firstname text, country text);
INSERT INTO customers2 VALUES ('Yeyo', 'Chile'),('Pepo', 'Chile');
```

```sql
create or replace procedure update_notifications_amount()
language plpgsql as $$
declare
  
  payment_cursor refcursor;
  payment_registry customers2%rowtype;
 
begin
    

  open payment_cursor  for select * from  customers2 c  where country  = 'Chile';
  loop
    fetch payment_cursor into payment_registry;
    exit when not found;
    
        if  payment_registry.firstname like 'Y%'  then
         
          raise notice 'commit1';     
          commit;
        else
          raise notice 'else';
          commit;
       end if;
         
    
  end loop;
  close payment_cursor;

end;
$$;

dell=# call update_notifications_amount();
NOTICE:  commit1
ERROR:  cursor "<unnamed portal 1>" does not exist
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function update_notifications_amount() line 12 at FETCH
```

Y el siguiente código es usando la declaracion dinámica del cursor y funciona bien, solución que puedes aplicar en tu caso, sustituyendo la declaracion dinamica por la linea del `OPEN cursor FOR SELECT` y definiendo el cursor con el mismo nombre que usaras en la declaración dinamica :

```sql
create or replace procedure update_notifications_amount()
language plpgsql as $$
declare
  c refcursor := 'payment_cursor';
  --payment_cursor refcursor;
  payment_registry customers2%rowtype;
 
begin
  /* usa SQL dinamico para tu cursor */
   EXECUTE $_$DECLARE payment_cursor CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
              select * from  customers2 c  where country  = 'Chile'$_$;

  --open payment_cursor  for select * from  customers c  where country  = 'Chile';
  loop
    fetch c into payment_registry;
    exit when not found;
    
        if  payment_registry.firstname like 'Y%'  then
         
          raise notice 'commit1';     
          commit;
        else
          raise notice 'else';
          commit;
       end if;
         
    
  end loop;
  close c;

end;
$$;

dell=# call update_notifications_amount();
NOTICE:  commit1
NOTICE:  else
CALL
```